# How to fill a shape with bitmap or mask a bitmap with shape in iText 7?

Tags: c#, itext, itext7

I want to fill a shape with a bitmap, in other words, mask a bitmap with a shape. I can't find a direct example. I am using iText 7 and C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can *fill a shape with a bitmap* by making that shape a clip path and adding the bitmap, e.g. like this:

```c#
using (PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(...))
using (PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(writer))
{
    ImageData data = ImageDataFactory.Create(...);

    PdfCanvas pdfCanvas = new PdfCanvas(pdfDoc.AddNewPage());
    pdfCanvas.SaveState()
             .MoveTo(100, 100)
             .LineTo(300, 200)
             .LineTo(400, 400)
             .LineTo(200, 300)
             .ClosePath()
             .EoClip()
             .EndPath();
    pdfCanvas.AddImageAt(data, 100, 100, false);
    pdfCanvas.RestoreState();
}
```

*([AddImageWithMask](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext7/blob/master/src/test/csharp/content/AddImageWithMask.cs#L17) test `testAddImageInShape`)*

The result looks like this:

[image]